# Can a factory-contract access/read/modify variables in generated child-contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix, solidity-0.5.x

at the moment I am experimenting with the factory/child-logic in solidity. With my factory contract I am able to create child contracts in which an auction is executed. Now I want to return a variable in my factory/master-contract defined in my child-contract (e.g. LowestBid). Is there a certain way this can be accomplished? At the moment I struggle with this problem and I don't find any answers here.
I just need a basic logic for interacting with values defined by my child in my factory.

Thanks in advance.

Current code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11; 

contract Master {

    address Pi_C_Owner;
    address payable public NewAuctionPayable;   

    constructor() public {
        Pi_C_Owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function checkBalance() public view returns(uint) { 
        require(msg.sender == Pi_C_Owner,"Insufficient permission");
        return(address(this).balance);
    }

    function increaseBalance() public payable {
        require(msg.sender == Pi_C_Owner,"Insufficient permission");
    }

    function createAuction(address _Destination, uint _WTP, uint _BiddingTime) public returns(address) {    
        require(_WTP > 0,"Willingness to pay has to exceed 0.");
        address NewAuction = address (new Auction(_Destination, _WTP, _BiddingTime, address(this)));
        NewAuctionPayable = address(uint160(NewAuction));
        NewAuctionPayable.transfer(_WTP);
        return(NewAuctionPayable);
    } 

    function Test() public returns(uint) {
        //how can i return a variable defined in child-contract 'Auction' (e.g. LowestBid)
    }

    function() external payable {
    }
}

contract Auction {

    bool Ended;
    uint WTP;
    uint public a8_AuctionEndTime;
    uint public a7_SafetyDeposit;
    uint public a6_LowestBid;
    address public a5_Destination;
    address payable MasterPayable;
    address payable LowestBidder;
    address payable Payee;

    struct Participant {
        bool biddingright;
        uint amount;
    }

    mapping(address => Participant) participants;
    address payable[] depositor;

    constructor(address _Destination, uint _WTP, uint _BiddingTime, address payable _Master) public {
        a5_Destination = _Destination;
        WTP = _WTP;
        a7_SafetyDeposit = _WTP/2;
        a6_LowestBid = _WTP;
        a8_AuctionEndTime = now + _BiddingTime;
        MasterPayable = _Master;
        Ended = false;
    }

    function a1_getRights() public payable { 
        require(now <= a8_AuctionEndTime,"Auction already ended.");
        require(msg.value >= a7_SafetyDeposit);
        require(participants[msg.sender].biddingright == false,"Safety deposit already payed.");
        participants[msg.sender].biddingright = true;
        participants[msg.sender].amount = msg.value;
        depositor.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function a2_placeBid(uint Bid) public {                                         
        require(now <= a8_AuctionEndTime,"Auction already ended.");
        require(Bid < a6_LowestBid,"There already is a lower bid.");
        require(participants[msg.sender].biddingright == true,"Please note safety deposit.");
        LowestBidder = msg.sender;
        a6_LowestBid = Bid;
    }

    function a3_AuctionEnd() public {
        require(now >= a8_AuctionEndTime,"Auction not yet ended.");
        require(Ended == false,"Auction end has already been called.");
        Ended = true;
        MasterPayable.transfer(WTP-a6_LowestBid);                          
        for(uint i=0; i<depositor.length; i++) {
            Payee = depositor[i];
            if(Payee != LowestBidder) {
                Payee.transfer(participants[Payee].amount);         
            }
        }
    }

    function() external payable {
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer to the title of your question (I didn't read all the rest) is No. You should add setter functions in your child contract, and if you want to allow them to be called only by the factory contract, then you should add appropriate protection in those functions.

Comment: `return Auction(NewAuctionPayable).LowestBid();`